# sudo: unable to resolve host <Computer Name>

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have tried the two answers [listed on SuperUser here](https://superuser.com/questions/1108197/sudo-on-windows-10-linux-subsystem-cannot-resolve-local-machine-name).

We have tried this `/etc/hostname`

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
127.0.0.1        localhost DESKTOP-AAAT5QS
```

...and this `/etc/hostname`

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
DESKTOP-AAAT5QS
```

In both cases, this is the outcome:

```
bigfont@DESKTOP-AAAT5QS:/mnt/c/Users/bigfo$ sudo apt-get install curl
sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-AAAT5QS
```

Comment: Is the first command by chance supposed to be `cat /etc/hosts`? If not, something is seriously odd about your hostname. ;)

Comment: Aha. I think what you're saying, is that I made a mistake using `hostname` instead of `hosts`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Add the hostname in **/etc/hosts** file:*

`127.0.0.1 DESKTOP-AAAT5QS`

*Save and Exit from the file*

*Now restart the server!*